# docker compose, multiple databases, execute postgres sql file from shell

Tags: postgresql, docker, shell, docker-compose

I am using docker-compose for creating multiple postgres databases, and I am able to create them but I need also to execute a sql file on each database, I used '\i db/app.sql' in create-multiple-postgresql-databases.sh file but when starting docker-compose it shows me this error.

```
db/app.sql: No such file or directory
```

this is the file structure:

```
├── dbscripts
│   └── postgres
│       └── db
│           └── app.sql
├── docker-compose.yml
```

here is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  postgres-service:
    image: postgres:latest
    container_name: postgres-container
    ports:
      - 55432:5432/tcp
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/postgres
      - ./dbscripts/postgres:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: ${DB_USER}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
      POSTGRES_MULTIPLE_DATABASES: app,app_test
      POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD: trust
```

create-multiple-postgresql-databases.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e
set -u

function create_user_and_database() {
    local database=$1
    echo "  Creating user and database '$database'"
    psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 --username "$POSTGRES_USER" <<-EOSQL
        CREATE USER $database;
        CREATE DATABASE $database;
        GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE $database TO $database;
        \connect $database;
        \i db/app.sql;
EOSQL
}

if [ -n "$POSTGRES_MULTIPLE_DATABASES" ]; then
    echo "Multiple database creation requested: $POSTGRES_MULTIPLE_DATABASES"
    for db in $(echo $POSTGRES_MULTIPLE_DATABASES | tr ',' ' '); do
        create_user_and_database $db
    done
    echo "Multiple databases created"
fi
```

Comment: Have you found the db/app.sql file? Maybe the relative path is off?

Comment: @Ruchi yes actually it was a path issue, the correct one is docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/db/app.sql